# How to use anchor tag to navigate to particular section of page in react/preact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#id1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#id2">AnotherMenu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#id3">AnotherMenuToo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="id1">
<someReactComponent></someReactComponent>
</div>

<div id="id3">
<someAnotherReactComponent></someAnotherReactComponent>
</div>

<div id="id2">
<someAnotherReactComponent></someAnotherReactComponent>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have multiple react/preact componenets in a single page. I want to navigate to particular section using anchor tag. Currently I am doing this by using click handler and navigating using scrollTo(). But I need to use scrollspy functionality so i have to use it in classis way. But when I am trying to navigate using href=#id , its showing **Cannot GET the requested resource** . Please help me out.

**Its all beacuse i need to implement scroll spy in my react/preact project**

Please help me guys.

Comment: share your code, that way it ll be easier to give a solution.

Comment: Where you wanna navigate add <a name=”#ToHere”>  and when you wanna go to it use <a href=”ToHere”> if its not working. Try to move the ”#” to the other one.

Comment: @VarunTheFalcon added the prototype. Its kinda same. Please let me know if more info is required

Comment: @Putte unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to define the `<div>` in the `<a>` tag with `name` attribute

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#id1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#id2">AnotherMenu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#id3">AnotherMenuToo</a></li>
</ul>

<a name="#id1">
    <div id="id1">
       <someReactComponent></someReactComponent>
    </div>
</a>

<a name="#id3">
    <div id="id3">
       <someReactComponent></someReactComponent>
    </div>
</a>

<a name="#id2">
    <div id="id2">
       <someReactComponent></someReactComponent>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basnal , Thanks for taking your time to help me. It scrolls there for fraction of time. but then navigates away and again displays Cannot GET the whatever resource.

Comment: @avisek1269 please try to implement the updated code.

Comment: Same problem. actually it updates the url. I mean it update url to sample.html#id1 and then that issue comes.